# Conditional counting R. Add if both rows==TRUE

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame of bacterial colony counts (ACCN) from two different methods of sampling: Swabs and Plates. I'd like to count the times when colony count agree for both methods for a series of standards (e.g. if ACCN<="2.5", etc.).

```
head(EA)
  sample group     ACCN
1      E     1 14.84500
2      S     1  2.07500
3      E     2 13.70167
4      S     2  6.60000
5      E     3 11.45833
6      S     3  7.90000
```

So far I've got:

```
S<-(EA$ACCN<="2.5" & EA$sample=="S")
P<-(EA$ACCN<="2.5" & EA$sample=="P")
PE<-cbind(S,P)
PE<-as.data.frame(PE)

sum(PE)
```

But receive this error: 
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

Comment: Try `PE<-cbind(as.numeric(S),as.numeric(P))`, etc. Note that considering the subject line of the question, I'm not sure that you don't want `?rowSums`.

Comment: Maybe construct a simpler example and show exactly what you want to get as the result?  The main problem I see with the methodology is what you do when one of the sample methods exceeds the criterion, and the other one does not -- is that a mismatch, or a match?

Comment: @user295691 that's a mismatch

Comment: I should have been clearer -- I don't mean "match" in the sense of whether the ACCNs match, but whether the criteria "<=2.5" applies.  Unless you're checking for the number of times that both sampling methods return a value less than the threshold?  If that is the case, then this is a very different question.

Answer (score 2):

With dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

EA %>%
  mutate(S = ifelse(as.numeric(ACCN) <= 2.5 & sample == "S", 1, 0)) %>% 
  mutate(P = ifelse(as.numeric(ACCN) <= 2.5 & sample == "P", 1, 0)) %>% 
  summarise(PE_sum = sum(S, P))
```

But, if you just want the dataframe by itself, then:

```
EA %>%
  mutate(S = ifelse(as.numeric(ACCN) <= 2.5 & sample == "S", 1, 0)) %>% 
  mutate(P = ifelse(as.numeric(ACCN) <= 2.5 & sample == "P", 1, 0))
```

If you don't care about having a distinct "P" and an "S" column, you can write it more succinctly:

```
EA %>% 
  mutate(new = ifelse(as.numeric(ACCN) <= 2.5 & sample %in% c("S", "P"), 1, 0)) %>% 
  summarise(new_sum = sum(new))
```

Or just use what you already have:

```
S<-(EA$ACCN<="2.5" & EA$sample=="S")
P<-(EA$ACCN<="2.5" & EA$sample=="P")
```

But, then:

```
sum(S, P)
```

Or:

```
S<-(EA$ACCN<="2.5" & EA$sample=="S")
P<-(EA$ACCN<="2.5" & EA$sample=="P")
PE<-cbind(S,P)
```

But then:

```
sum(PE) # keeping the object a matrix, not spinning it into a dataframe.
```

To get the sum, for each value from 1 to 30 (optional), as per your question in the comment section, an answer could be:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- 1:30
(sapply(x, function(x) {ifelse(as.numeric(EA$ACCN) <= x & EA$sample == "S", 1, 0)}) +
sapply(x, function(x) {ifelse(as.numeric(EA$ACCN) <= x & EA$sample == "P", 1, 0)})) %>%  
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  summarise_all(sum)
```

Though I don't know the exact structure of the output that you're seeking.

Comment: Why `as.numeric(ACCN)`? And why not `as.numeric(ACCN <= 2.5 & sample == "S")` instead of `ifelse`?

Comment: Because the "sample" variable is either a factor or a character class?

Comment: But `sample == "S"` is `logical`.

Comment: True. Good point. You can do either. Or just keep the ACCN variable a character class.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. What happens if I wanted to do this for lots of different ACCN values, e.g. 1 to 30. Is there a way of making this without a for loop?

Comment: Can you explain yourself better? Do you mean values of `ACCN` for each `sample` equal to `"S"` and `"P"`?

Comment: I could see you just making a standalone vector of integers from `1:30`, then running one of the functions from the apply family over it.

Comment: @HCAI: By the way, `sample` is a really bad name for an object since it already is the name of an `base R` function.

Comment: @HCAI: `x <- 1:30; sapply(x, function(x) {ifelse(as.numeric(EA$ACCN <= x & EA$sample == "S"), 1, 0)})` I don't know the exact structure of the output you want, though.

Comment: @HCAI: check the edit for an answer to your 1 to 30 scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is really nice. The idea was to test whether the sample had a bacterial count of less than a set standard (initially 2.5) but then to compare against other standards (e.g. 1 to 30 bacteria per sample).

Comment: @Odysseus210 I've just realised that the output of the last piece of code gives a big data frame of many rows and columns (corresponding the the length of x). I'd expect to see one row and many columns. Any thoughts why? For example I tried it just for "S" samples and it should be only a vector.

Comment: The last piece of code, i.e., the one in the comment section? This one: `x <- 1:30; sapply(x, function(x) {ifelse(as.numeric(EA$ACCN <= x & EA$sample == "S"), 1, 0)})`? Would indeed give a matrix of many rows and columns, as intended. Just use the last block of code in my *answer* to get one row and many columns. Please provide further feedback if this  is not a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Odysseus210 I did this first and used dmean as the input for your code and it works nicely. dmean<-aggregate(data=EA,ACCN~phase+sample+group,mean). It must have been because my data had more groups than I posed above. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The error message comes from the sum function--it takes a vector as an argument rather than a data frame. Summing the logical vectors directly works:

```
sum(S)
[1] 2

sum(P)
[1] 3

sum(S & P)
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have made this problem more complicated than you intended.  It sounds like you want to filter out some data and test it.

Start with the data:

```
EA <- read.table(text='  ACC ACCN sample
+ 1  SG 1.50      S
+ 2  LG 7.25      S
+ 3  SG 1.50      S
+ 4  NG 0.00      P
+ 5  SG 1.50      P
+ 6  SG 1.50      P ')
```

Filter and split/apply/combine:

```
> EA %>%
  filter(ACCN <= 2.5) %>%
  group_by(sample) %>%
  summarise(count=n())
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  sample count
  <fctr> <int>
1      P     3
2      S     2
```

If you want the margins (that is, the percentage of samples that meet the criterion), then you can be a bit trickier

```
> EA %>% group_by(sample) %>% summarise(pct=sum(ACCN <= 2.5) / n())
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  sample       pct
  <fctr>     <dbl>
1      P 1.0000000
2      S 0.6666667
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this. I have realised that the S and the P are actually paired. E.g. value in row 1 is a pair with value in row 4, 2 and 5, 3 and 6. I'm really sorry for the confusion. I want to test when these pairs are the same. I have actually got the initial table to represent this by a separate "group" column. I've altered my question to reflect this properly. Again, sorry for this.